# aws-s3 gem: Disable automatic bucket creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I'm using the `aws-s3` gem to connect to s3 and upload files.  I have a model that isn't related to aws (legacy model) with the word Bucket in the classname: TagBucket (for a tag grouping).  When I enabled aws-s3, though, I noticed what appears to be undocumented behavior: the gem seems to find any class with `"Bucket"` in the name and over-ride it's inheritance.  It should inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`, but with aws/s3 required, it now inherits from `AWS::S3::Bucket` and breaks my app.  Is there a way to disable this behavior?